# Linebreaks are not show up using PHPExcel_RichText()

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPExcel to export into an excel file and new lines worked great until I needed to use `PHPExcel_RichText()` to get different formatting in the same cell. Is there any way around this? (I know that PHPspreadsheet is available but I have to use PHPExcel). I found a few threads about similar issues but no solutions unfortunately.

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();

$run1 = $objRichText->createTextRun("Line one\n this does not work");
$run1->getFont()->applyFromArray(array( "bold" => true, "size" => 24, "name" => "Calibri", "color" => array("rgb" => "333333")));

$objRichText->createText("\n this does not work either \r\n and not this");

$run2 = $objRichText->createTextRun("Line two");
$run2->getFont()->applyFromArray(array( "bold" => true, "size" => 16, "name" => "Calibri", "color" => array("rgb" => "333333")));

$objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, $objRichText);
```

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Trying the `PHP_EOL` instead of '\n' solved the issue for me

```
$objRichText->createText(PHP_EOL);
```

- DOS - Uses a CR+LF (that's ASCII 13 followed by an ASCII 10, or `\r\n`) to represent a new line.
- Unix - Uses an LF (that's ASCII 10, or `\n`) to represent a new line.
- Mac (pre-OS X) - Uses a CR (that's ASCII 13, or `\r`) to represent a new line.
- Mac (OS X) - Like Unix, uses an LF to represent a new line.

`PHP_EOL` will automatically choose the correct character for the platform, so that your new lines are platform-independent.

Comment: I tried that too earlier, but it didn’t work when replacing my \n with ”.PHP_EOL.” but I never tried to only have PHP_EOL in a createText(). Do you get my example to work in Excel on Mac? How do I make an ’LF’ so I can try it directly?

Comment: I think I actually tried to only have PHP_EOL in the createText() as well without luck. I can try it again when I get back to the computer.

Comment: `$objRichText = str_replace('\r\n',"<br/>",$objRichText);` should do the trick

Comment: It gives me linebreaks, but removes all the formatting, which is why I'm using `PHPExcel_RichText()` and `createTextRun()` to begin with. Any other ideas? Thank you again

Comment: Is it working in Windows and Linux? Also, do you need a solution only for Mac or other OS also ?

Comment: I have no way to try Windows and Linux, but I'm mainly interested in Mac. It's so weird. linebreaks are working perfectly until I want to have different font sizes on different lines, then I either have to choose between linebreaks or formatting.

Comment: Do you have other ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Its an issue which has been already raised in [Github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1030)

Comment: Ah look at that. No solution there either huh :/

Comment: Ya... So we can close this here. You can comment on the Github post and wait for a fix. Else, the best way is using `PHPspreadsheet`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to ensure the cell has WrapText set...

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I came here looking for a hint on how to make line breaks work in https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs and this answer saved my life and brain sanity. Without wrapText on a cell you will never see your linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be work for you.

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
    $objRichText->createText('XYZ ');
    $objPayable = $objRichText->createTextRun('ABC');
    $objRichText->createTextRun("\r\n");
    $objPayable->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPayable->getFont()->setItalic(true);
    $objPayable->getFont()->setColor( new PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_DARKGREEN ) );

    $objRichText->createText(', unless specified otherwise on the invoice.');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', 'Rich Text')
                                  ->setCellValue('C1', $objRichText);


    $objRichText2 = new PHPExcel_RichText();
    $objRichText2->createText("black text\n");

    $objRed = $objRichText2->createTextRun("red text");
    $objRed->getFont()->setColor( new PHPExcel_Style_Color(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED  ) );

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("C2")->setValue($objRichText2);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("C2")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is kind of bizarre. It actually did work what I have, but I need to either select a cell and copy paste it somewhere else or save the document and unfocus Excel and focus it again before all the linebreaks jumps into place. Buggy. So they are there, they just don't show up until I change something random in the document. Anyone have experience with that?

Comment: Look what happens on copy paste, it snaps into place. Really need this to work right away though :/ https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9ca1zkhttma64g/Excel-bug.mov?dl=0